# Revert while loop's blocking tendency without concurrency (threading or multithreading)

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio

I am building a program that plays music and outputs text simultaneously (both occurring in the same time range, ps infinity unless interrupted by keyboard input because while loop  is being used), using playsound library. I stopped the blocking nature of the function by specifying `block=False` while inputting the file location.

Now I want to loop itself, but both the text and this playsound function had a while loop for themselves, so both could not occur together. Putting both of them in the same while loop is a good idea, but the problem is it gives a buzzing sound since we have to wait 18 seconds. Inserting `time.sleep` causes the text to be delayed, too.

```
# Wallpaper                                                                                                             import random

import time
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint
from playsound import playsound
time.sleep(0.5)
while 1:
        letters = str(random.choice(["a", "b"]))
        time.sleep(0.00000001)
        print(colored(letters, random.choice(["green", "blue"])))
        time.sleep(18)
        playsound("/home/AruJ/Downloads/loremipsum.mp3", block=False)
```

Comment: If you are on Windows, `winsound` has a `SND_LOOP` option.

Comment: @Arjun I think that lib only plays .wav and not .mp3. So based on your update, it might not work for you.

Comment: @001 No Issues. Thanks for letting me know about the module

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to play a sound for some known duration and while the sound is playing, print random text. While I don't know or have `playsound()` installed, my intuition tells me you are looking for something like this:

```py
import random
import time
from termcolor import colored, cprint
from playsound import playsound

sound_path = "/home/AruJ/Downloads/loremipsum.mp3"
duration = 18

while True:
    start_time = time.time()
    playsound(sound_path, block=False)

    while time.time() - start_time < duration:
        letters = random.choice(["a", "b"])
        colors = random.choice(["green", "blue"])
        print(colored(letters, colors))
        time.sleep(0.01)

    time.sleep(1.0)
```

Comment: Wow, That solution worked perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help!!